# How to display a big list of links into 4 columns but in tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on my company's directory-type website. We have some pages with multiple clickable links, but displayed in tables.

I would like something like this solution (for a similar question): http://jsfiddle.net/Fa722/270/  BUT with the table/colors I have chosen in the code snippet below.

Below is what it looks like now. Problem is I have to do this by hand.. AKA typing them out alphabetically then manually placing them (copy/paste) into the proper section.

It's okay for small lists... NOT for BIG lists. We sometimes have hundreds of links.

```css
table.minimalistBlack {
  background-color: #c1b089;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
table.minimalistBlack td, table.minimalistBlack th {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 4px;
}
table.minimalistBlack tfoot td {
}
```

```html
<table class="minimalistBlack">
<tbody>




<tr>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc1.com">Abc1</a></td>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc3.com">Abc3</a></td>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc5.com">Abc5</a></td>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc7.com">Abc7</a></td>
<tr>



<tr>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc2.com">Abc2</a></td>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc4.com">Abc4</a></td>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc6.com">Abc6</a></td>
<td><a href="/http://www.abc8.com">Abc8</a></td>
<tr>





</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you looking to achieve by asking this? Your intentions are unclear. Are you looking for a way to sort these alphabetically & then put the items from each set of data (4 sets of data in total) into a seperate table? Or are you wanting to sort these alphabetically (automatically) and then put them into _ONE_ table with 4 columns?

Comment: I am looking to put a giant list of <td><a href=""></a></td> links into 4 columns, alphabetically. It could be only 8 links. It could be 100 links. I only want one table with 4 columns.

Comment: How do you recieve the data? Is it already as a prefilled table or do you get an `<a>` tag? or do you just get a title and a link?

Comment: EGC: We make a list as we go. So it's simply a link to a website, but a big list is ugly, so I'm looking for a solution where no matter how many links I add, the columns will stay at 4, but the list will get bigger, automatically.

Comment: EGC: Does that clarify my question?

Comment: It does, and I've half-made a solution, however the sorting algorithm required is more complicated than you'd think. With elements like `Abc8` an alphanumeric sort is required, and Javascript's alphanumeric sort doesn't appear to support sorting an element with a digit on the end (it seems to only sort alphabetically, and when the digit is at the start then it will sort alphanumerically). So, my question to you, so that I might think about an alternate solution - give me some _real_ item names such as `Abc2` or `Abc8` so that I can attempt to make a better sorting algorithm